# In TeamCity, trigger build with 2 VCS roots with 2 custom revisions using REST API

Tags: rest, teamcity

looking for collective wisdom on this problem I am tackling.

I need to trigger build using REST API on TeamCity. The build configuration has 2 VCS roots and I need to pass specific revision for both of them. In documentation, I found example for single VCS, but I am stuck on setting revisions for both of them.

I am trying to set up something like this:

```
{
  "buildType": {
    "id": "ExampleConfiguration"
  },
  "defaultBranch": "false",
  "lastChanges": {
    "change": [
      {
        "locator": "combination of locators that will set VCS 1 - branch + revision"
      },
      {
        "locator": "combination of locators that will set VCS 2 - branch + revision"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In principle, I am simulating execution of the build, where both revisions are manually set - this is possible in the UI.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/rest/start-and-cancel-builds.html#Advanced+Build+Run

TC version: 2022.04.3 (build 108706)

Edit:
I was able to detect the changes and resolve their id on both VCS roots. For the changes field in the body I can now use locator of the form  `{"id": 123456}`. But another obstacle on the road, if I specify pair of these changes:

```
"lastChanges": { "change": [ {"id": 1}, {"id": 2} ] }
```

I get error

```
Responding with error, status code: 400 (Bad Request).
Details: jetbrains.buildServer.server.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Several non-personal changes are submitted, only one can be present
Invalid request. Please check the request URL and data are correct.
```

Same build with the exact revisions is possible to trigger manually from TC UI.

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved it. The way to go is to use `revisions` instead of `lastChanges`. To pass revisions for 2 VCS roots together with branch names, use this:

```
  "revisions": {
    "revision": [
      {
        "vcs-root-instance": {
          "id": "111"
        },
        "vcsBranchName": "branch-name-111",
        "version": "rev_on_vcs_111"
      },
      {
        "vcs-root-instance": {
          "id": "222"
        },
        "vcsBranchName": "branch-name-222",
        "version": "rev_on_vcs_222"
      }
    ]
  }
```

To resolve VCS root instance id, use API call `/app/rest/vcs-root-instances/vcsRoot:(id:(Project_Vcs_Root))"`